# pointwise and uniformly convergence of a function series

Tags: real-analysis

I have this series $\sum {{n+5}\over{3^n}} (1+log|x|)^{n+1}$.

Can i use the ratio test to study the pointwise convergence?

Comment: Yes, the ratio test works.

Comment: I have found pointwise convergence in $(-e^2,-e^{-4})\cup(e^{-4},e^2)$.But for the uniform convergence?

Comment: That's correct. Do you know where the series converges uniformly?

Comment: $f_n(x)$ are pair. If i calculate $f'_n(x)$ i found sup $|f_n(x)|=max \{{f_n(e^{-4}),f_n(e^2)}\}$

Comment: Well, unfortunately that doesn't help much here, since the series doesn't converge uniformly on the whole set $(-e^2,-e^{-4}) \cup (e^{-4},e^2)$. Do you know an what sets the series $\sum \frac{n+5}{3^n} t^{n+1}$ converges uniformly?

Comment: in every closed interval in $(-e^2,-e^{-4})\cup(e^{-4},e^2)$

Comment: That's for the $(1 + \log \lvert x\rvert)^{n+1}$ series. Right.

Comment: If i want calculate the sum of the series for x=1 can i use the geometric series?

Comment: Depends on what you mean with "use". It's not a straight geometric series, but closely related (a differentiated geometric series, basically). To evaluate it, using geometric series is standard, but you need a little more than just geometric series.